# MySQL timeout on INSERT lasts almost 60 seconds

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ClusterDescription` (
  `ClusterDescriptionId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ClusterId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RightBarDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `InstrumentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RowCreated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClusterDescriptionId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ClusterInstrumentId` (`ClusterId`,`InstrumentId`),
  KEY `InstrumentId` (`InstrumentId`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `OrderDesc` (`RightBarDateTime` DESC,`ClusterId` DESC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3055989 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

The table has more than 3m rows.

I receive regularly this error:

> SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when
>   trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

for this command:

```
INSERT INTO ClusterDescription (ClusterId, RightBarDateTime, InstrumentId)
 SELECT IFNULL(MAX(ClusterId) + 1, 1), :rightBarDateTime, :instrumentId
 FROM ClusterDescription WHERE InstrumentId = :instrumentId
```

- There can be up to 50 above INSERT at almost the same time.
- `:instrumentId` is never the same in any of the parallel commands.
- Checking the process list I see lot of these commands waiting to be executed with a `Time` value > 30 seconds.
- I set `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` to 360 seconds which improved the situation. Before I received lot of the above mentioned error and this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction

**My questions:**

- What is wrong with this table definition?
- Why do need the parallel INSERT commands more than 50 seconds to be executed?
- Why do I receive a `dead lock` error when only 1 table is affected?

Running on MySQL 8.0.13

I need the `InnoDB` engine because of the descending index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these improve the efficiency of the `SELECT MAX...` in the `INSERT..SELECT`:

**Plan A**

```
UNIQUE KEY `ClusterInstrumentId` (`ClusterId`,`InstrumentId`),
KEY `InstrumentId` (`InstrumentId`, ClusterId) USING BTREE,
```

This assumes you need to look up things by `ClusterId`.

**Plan B**

```
UNIQUE (`InstrumentId`, ClusterId)
```

This covers the Uniqueness constraint

Comment: I applied **PLAN B**. I will check the log files tomorrow morning and let you know/accept this answer. That far it looks very good what I see in the few minutes it is running with the new index. THX!

Comment: Yes, now the `INSERT` command is executed instantly. The Dead Lock error message and all other don't appear anymore. Enjoy your Banana Latte!

Comment: @RickJames Can you please explain how this is working ? I have a similar issue in one of our tables where inserts takes more than 30s.

Comment: @user3279954 - Please start a new question with your specific table and query.  It is likely that there is something subtle that makes it different than the table or query here.